# filter element not rendered as in browser

Tags: svg, svg-filters, batik

I'm trying to create my own sky atlas using 
[wikimedia constellation images](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Leo_IAU.svg) in SVG. If you display them in a browser, the background - except for the area of the constellation itself - appears a solid medium grey. To test how it can be displayed in a Java application, I have taken [class SVGApplication](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html) from the Batik documentation. It works - almost: the grey background is now reduced to some rectangles with wide white gaps between them.

[image: Result of SVGApplication]

As far as I can decipher SVG, this is the filter definition and use:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="485.028pt" height="456.053pt"
     viewBox="0 0 485.028 456.053" version="1.1">
<!-- ... -->
<filter id="alpha" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
<mask id="mask0">
  <g filter="url(#alpha)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="486" height="457" style="fill:rgb(100%,100%,100%);fill-opacity:0.149994;stroke:none;"/>
  </g>
</mask>
<clipPath id="clip4">
  <rect width="421" height="385"/>
</clipPath>
<!-- ... -->
</svg>
```

The Java code is very simple, using a JFileChooser to select a file and feed the JSVGCanvas with it. The essential lines are:

```
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Batik");
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JSVGCanvas svgCanvas = new JSVGCanvas();
    panel.add("Center", svgCanvas);
    File file = new File( "aaa.svg" );
    svgCanvas.setURI(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
    f.getContentPane().add( panel );
    f.setSize(600, 600);
    f.setVisible(true);
```

What needs to be done to have the background appear as in the browser?

**Edit**
This is a simplified version of the SVG having the same effect - works in a browser but does not in the Java program.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      width="485.028pt" height="456.053pt"
      viewBox="0 0 485.028 456.053" version="1.1">
    <defs>
    <filter id="alpha" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask0">
      <g filter="url(#alpha)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="486" height="457" style="fill:rgb(100%,100%,100%);fill-opacity:0.149994;stroke:none;"/>
      </g>
    </mask>

    <g id="surface2">
    <path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.730068%,12.159915%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 376.316406 213.578125 L 351.210938 219.398438 L 333.015625 222.675781 L 336.652344 243.417969 L 309.726562 248.511719 L 310.457031 254.695312 L 296.265625 256.878906 L 282.4375 258.335938 L 285.347656 287.808594 L 278.070312 289.265625 L 282.4375 339.847656 L 272.976562 340.9375 L 274.070312 350.035156 L 244.597656 351.855469 L 207.480469 353.308594 L 183.828125 352.21875 L 184.554688 329.292969 L 201.660156 248.511719 L 176.914062 247.417969 L 154.355469 245.964844 L 125.246094 242.6875 L 127.429688 226.3125 L 109.964844 223.402344 L 86.675781 219.035156 L 65.570312 214.304688 L 69.210938 199.75 L 48.46875 195.015625 L 16.449219 184.464844 L 52.835938 71.296875 L 71.390625 76.753906 L 91.40625 82.210938 L 84.855469 111.324219 L 117.242188 117.511719 L 122.335938 92.402344 L 169.273438 98.222656 L 167.089844 114.960938 L 188.558594 116.054688 L 238.046875 133.886719 L 253.328125 114.960938 L 277.707031 112.050781 L 303.90625 108.050781 L 317.003906 66.203125 L 336.652344 61.105469 L 353.027344 55.648438 L 399.605469 206.664062 L 376.316406 213.578125 Z M 0.800781 384.96875 L 420.34375 384.96875 L 420.34375 0.335938 L 0.800781 0.335938 L 0.800781 384.96875 Z M 0.800781 384.96875 "/>
    </g>

    </defs>
    <g id="surface0">
    <use xlink:href="#surface2"  transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,33,18)" mask="url(#mask0)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

(I admit that I have no experience with SVG. I'm willing to RTFM, but where do I start?)

Comment: Asstated, this question is probably going to end up being voted for closure. There are too many unknowns here, and unless someone has struck the exact same problem, any answers would just be a guess.  It would help a lot if you can reduce the SVG to something minimal that reproduces the problem. Then post that.

Comment: You're not providing a minimal test case - but that filter/mask combination doesn't look like the culprit anyway- the filter just takes the input and passes through the alpha but sets the RGB to white - which the mask's rect IS already, so it shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @MichaelMullany The simplified full SVG which I've added contains nothing but one path using that mask - and has almost the same effect as the original code except that the vertical white stripe after 12h is absent.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau Thanks to you and Michael - see my comment to him.

Comment: So when rendered in your Java app, you are seeing five horizontal white stripes?

Comment: NVM. I checked it in Batik Squiggle and it does appear to be Batik at fault.  Not anything you are doing.  I guess report the bug to the Batik team.  As for workarounds, I am not sure what you can do. I am assuming you probably don't have much control over the SVGs generated (?).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks for the very useful comment. Do you have answers to my follow-ups: (1) I can twiddle the SVG if I knew which SVG code would solve the problem. (2) Why does it work in Firefox? Or is there another good way of displaying SVG using Java?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau These SVG files aren't my doing - they are straight from wiki[mp]edia. I don't know how they originated; the original source IAU and/or Sky&Teleskope publishes the same maps in other formats. I thought that SVG would be preferable for manipulating, i.e., display in nightly dark red, rotation, scaling...

Comment: (1) See the answer I posted. (2) Because there is nothing wrong with the SVG. It's just Batik that that has the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your guess is correct about it being the mask and filter combination that is causing problems with Batik, try this workaround.

We'll make a quick and dirty replacement of the offending element with something that is a close equivalent.

Approx nine lines from the end of the file, you will find the following:

```
<use xlink:href="#surface2" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,33,18)" mask="url(#mask0)"/>
```

Try changing this to

```
<use xlink:href="#surface2" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,33,18)" opacity="0.15"/>
```

The modified file seems to render identically to the original, and works fine in Batik - at least for me.

Hopefully the rest of your SVG files have the same file arrangement and are as easy to fix.

Good luck!

Comment: Much obliged! - All the *_IAU.svg for the 88 official constellations are built  identically. I know enough XSLT to apply your patch automatically.

Comment: FYI, bug reported on the SVG issues site.